# Converting SQL query to Hibernate query

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I need help converting some sql to hibernate sql.

SQL:

```
String sql = "select time, hour(time) as hour, minute(time) as minute "
           + "from db where time >= DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -24 HOUR) "
           + "group by 2 order by time LIMIT 500";
```

I use SQLQuery to add scalars. I tried this for HQL:

```
String hql = "select time, hour(time), minute(time) from db as O "
           + "where O.time >= :time group by 2 order by O.time";

Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setDate("time", calend.getTime()); //calend is a Calendar object
```

However, this doesn't work. Error says it's an hql error.

Comment: as you are using only one table, try without the table alias.

Comment: I still get the same error if I do it without the table alias.

Comment: Try `GROUP BY hour(time)` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `setDate` try using `setParameter`.

From [this link about HQL dates:](http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/java/hql-date-datetime-quick-tip/)

> "setDate" will truncate the HQL date value and ignore the hours, minutes, seconds.

Using `setParameter` will interpret the values as the parameter that you indicated by `:variable`.